# Redirect query results to another page flask

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I'm making a page with Python Flask to run an elasticsearch query then pass the result to another "result" page, but None is what i get while the correct result displayed in the console when i restart the app.

Below code to run,

```
class Kannel(Form):
number = StringField('MSISDN', [validators.Length(max=16)])
ID = StringField('MessageID', [validators.Length(max=50)])

@app.route('/Kannel', methods=['POST','GET'])
def kannel():
    form = Kannel(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        number = request.form['number']
        ID = request.form['ID']
        res = search(number)
        session['res'] = res
        flash("Redirecting to results ...")
        return redirect(url_for('result'))
    else:       
        return render_template('kannel.html', form=form)

@app.route('/result', methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    output = session.get('res')
    return render_template('result.html', output=output)
```

The search() is the query to run within other file, it runs correctly as mentioned.

Any ideas how to achieve that ??

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect(url_for('.result'))
```

should be:

```
return redirect(url_for('result'))
```

No need for the dot.

Unless you want to redefine this:

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET','POST'])
```

But I guess that's possibly a typo.

On the other hand, you might need to check the size of the data you are trying to put into session. If it exceeds cookie size supported by browsers, it will not get set.

Comment: Yes a typo, thanks for your notification, but this doesn't affect with the issue.

Comment: Trying printing session ['res'] immediately after setting it to see what happens. And see my updated answer as well. That might be the reason

Comment: The data size isn't that large it's a few it's just  5 short lines repeated 4 times max, is there a better way to accomplish this ?

Comment: One way to be sure it's not the size is for you to try setting a string in the session and see if it shows up in your result route. For most browser, cookie should not exceed 4096 bytes or so.